# How to transfer some information between 2 pages or more ?

Tags: tapestry

I'm *currently learning how to use tapestry 5.3.6 and i have one issue. I need to share information between 2 pages to do a full registration for a user to a fake mobile operator and i don't know what is the right way to do this, firstly i thought that the @Persist could do this trick but i realized that this annotation keep information for a specific page eand don't share it with other pages... I think the @SessionStated is the answer but i'm not sure :/

Here is a schema to illustrate my needing :

First page : "personnal information" => Second page "credit card information" => Third page : "Resume and policies acceptation before final submission"

I hope that you can help me... Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with @SessionAttribute, @SessionState and through Session.

1. Session attributes:

   ```
   @SessionAtribute("myObject")
   private MyObject myObject;
   ```
2. Session-wide objects:

   ```
   @SessionState
   private MyObject myObject;
   ```
3. Session API:

   ```
   @Inject
   private Request request;

   void someMethod() {
     final Session session = request.getSession(true);
     session.setAttribute("myObject", myObject);
   }
   ```

More information [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/session-storage.html)

Comment: Is it correct to use the session for this kind of information ? Because i thought that the session is here for example to keep some information about a logged user ? But not to share some temporary information between forms

Comment: Tapestry gives you a lot of options; in some cases, you can use the page activation context of the 2nd page to pass information from the first page (if it is just a simple string or number). I visualize this as a "bucket brigade" where each page is responsible for passing some data to the next.

Comment: @SessionState is often used to store complex data where successive pages edit a portion of it: that is, a multi-page wizard.

I generally would not use the 3rd option; the first two options cover all those cases.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with various method which are explained on this link : http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/state/passingbypersist

We can use the session, or use the @Persist, for the persist method we need to implement a public method to pass parameters to the next page which is going to be called.

The second solution was the solution I was looking for.